# Setting SFTP configuration property value by using respective message header key value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have one requirement to connect SFTP server based on the configuration provided . The configuration will varry and it is provided inside the headers with proper key. I want to get the values from the key to set respective bean property value as mentioned below. I have done the changes but it showing "Unknown host exception" Could anyone please help me on this ?

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
                <property name="allowUnknownKeys" value="true" />
                <property name="host" value="headers['SFTP_SERVER']" />
                <property name="privateKey"
                    value="headers['SFTP_KEY']" />
                <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="" />
                <property name="port" value="headers['SFTP_PORT']" />
                <property name="user" value="headers['SFTP_USER']" />
                <property name="password" value="headers.SFTP_PASSWORD" />
            </bean>
```

Comment: Why do you use `spring-integration-aws` tag? On the other hand I don't see reason in the `spring-integration-sftp` as well... I wonder if we can remove them...

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work the way you see it. Such a `sftpSessionFactory` `<bean>` is going to be created only once during application startup and those SpEL-like property values don't bring any value in this phase: there is just no any message to interact with. Please, learn what are beans in Spring and how they are initialized: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core

The only solution for your headers-based use-case can be done via `DelegatingSessionFactory` and custom `SessionFactoryLocator` where you create an instance of the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` on the fly. You can cache them, of course, over there, because different messages may bring the same property values in their headers. Don't forget to store some `key` in the `ThreadLocal`:

```
/**
 * Set a key to be used for {@link #getSession()} on this thread.
 * @param key the key.
 */
public void setThreadKey(Object key) {
    this.threadKey.set(key);
}
```

Otherwise the `DelegatingSessionFactory`  is not going to work.

See more info in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#sftp-dsf

Comment: See [the dynamic ftp sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) for an example of how to dynamically create adapters on demand.